# emacs in interactive mode (activated by M-X) when I press "enter" it creates new line instead of executing

Tags: emacs

I am not sure what I did exactly, but I remember pressing C-U or something while working in emacs, and after that I can no longer execute commands in interactive mini-buffer. For example, I pressed M-x, then "gdb", then ENTER. I get a new line, instead of a running GDB..

I then surprisingly realized that it is permanent. The behavior persists even I restart emacs, or even my shell, in a desperate attempt.

This is a big bummer.. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you use C-j instead of <enter>?

Comment: same as <enter> it gives me a new line

Comment: To help diagnose this, please add what you see when you do `M-x view-lossage` immediately after experiencing the problem.

Comment: I can't execute view-lossage.. I press <enter> it creates a new line in the mini-buffer

Comment: Can you run `emacs -q`?

Comment: yeah I can do that and i don't see the problem. However I cannot figure out how I could have possibly edited my .emacs while running emacs or exactly what I changed :(

Comment: Ok, instead of `M-x view-lossage` try `C-h l`

Comment: You can always do what I do when I screw up my emacs config: delete half of your .emacs and see if the problem is fixed. Repeat until it works; the last section you deleted is causing the problem. Not elegant or satisfying, but unless your .emacs is huge you should be able to solve identify the problem in 15 minutes or so.

Comment: yep I could do that. I somehow made it work I really don't know how. Thanks for the help guys. I will post here if I figure out the cause.